# Function not replacing values matched by the key inside an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

for some reason, the "placeholder" aren't being changed.

I've edited this code and I'm afriad I've broken something, as it did work before.

As you can see `setPopInputs('value')` have a value, which matches the keys inside the object array. I don't understand why it isn't changing the value of the input fields inside the form.

Any help would be appriciated.

Thank you

```
<div>
    <input type="image" value="ru" class="zastave" src="assets/drzave/Rus.png" onclick="rewrite('ru'); setPopInputs('ru');">
    <input type="image" value="hr" class="zastave" src="assets/drzave/Hrv.png" onclick="rewrite('hr'); setPopInputs('hr');">
    <input type="image" value="it" class="zastave" src="assets/drzave/Ita.png" onclick="rewrite('it'); setPopInputs('it');">
    <input type="image" value="de" class="zastave" src="assets/drzave/Nem.png" onclick="rewrite('de'); setPopInputs('de');">
    <input type="image" value="en" class="zastave" src="assets/drzave/Ang.png" onclick="rewrite('en'); setPopInputs('en');">
    <input type="image" value="sl" class="zastave" src="assets/drzave/Slo.png" onclick="rewrite('sl'); setPopInputs('sl');">
</div>

html code 
and more html code

<input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z][^0-9]{2,25}" name="popupfname" id="popupfname" placeholder="Janez"autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" /><br />
<span id="pf" class="error pfn" aria-live="polite"></span><br />
<input type="email" name="popupemail" id="popupemail" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" maxlength="45" placeholder="moj@email.si"/><br />
<span id="pe" class="error pem" aria-live="polite"></span><br />
```

```
placeholders = {
    sl: { fname: "Janez", lname: "Novak", email: "moj@email.si" },
    en: { fname: "John", lname: "Doe", email: "my@email.us" }, 
    de: { fname: "Kommissar", lname: "Rex", email: "mein@email.deu" },
    it: { fname: "Fabio", lname: "Marggeriti", email: "barilla@email.it"},
    hr: { fname: "Mirko", lname: "Mirosavljevic", email: "moj@email.hr"},
    ru: { fname: "Mikayl", lname: "Rus", email: "moji@email.ru"}
}; 


function setPopInputs(language) {  
let pfname = document.getElementById('popupfname');
let pemail = document.getElementById('popupemail');
    if (Object.keys(placeholders).includes(language)){
        const values = placeholders[language];
            pfname.setAttribute("placeholder", values.fname);
            pemail.setAttribute("placeholder", values.email);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you done any debugging to see where it may be going wrong?

Comment: working as expected, may be you have not defined `rewrite` function

Comment: Just double checking you only want to change the placeholder attribute? If the inputs have any value other than empty, the placeholder won't show.